# How to select nodes that belong to a specific tree(level) using JSTREE

Tags: javascript, jstree

I'm trying to make a rule which makes the user select only nodes that belong to a specific tree ; The user mustn't have the possibily to choose multiple nodes from different levels like this :

[image: the problem]

Do you have any idea how to do so ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the way to do so is (not sure if there's an easier way) to listen on the select_node event and check if the selected node has the same parent as the other selected nodes... if i succed, i'll post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution if anyone is facing the same issue :

the html part :

```
<div id="jstree"/>
```

The javascript part :

```
$(function() {$("#jstree").on("select_node.jstree", function (evt, data) {

  var selectedNode= $('#jstree').jstree(true).get_selected(true);

  for(var i = 0, j = selectedNode.length; i < j; i++) {

    if(selectedNode.length > 1){

        var res = selectedNode[i].parents[selectedNode[i].parents.length-2];

      if(data.node.parent != res){
            $('#jstree').jstree("deselect_all");
      }

    }

  }

});

$('#jstree').jstree({
    'core': {

        'data': [{
            "id": "1.0",
            "text": "Fresh Products",
            "icon": "",
            "state": {
                "opened": false,
                "disabled": false,
                "selected": false
            },
            "children": [{
                "id": "2.06.0",
                "text": "Ethnic & Specialty",
                "icon": "",
                "state": {
                    "opened": false,
                    "disabled": false,
                    "selected": false
                },
                "children": [{
                "id": "2.16.0",
                "text": "Ethnic & Specialty",
                "icon": "",
                "state": {
                    "opened": false,
                    "disabled": false,
                    "selected": false
                },
                "children": false,
                "liAttributes": null,
                "aAttributes": null
            }, {
                "id": "2.17.0",
                "text": "Natural & Organic",
                "icon": "",
                "state": {
                    "opened": false,
                    "disabled": false,
                    "selected": false
                },
                "children": false,
                "liAttributes": null,
                "aAttributes": null
            }],
                "liAttributes": null,
                "aAttributes": null
            }, {
                "id": "2.07.0",
                "text": "Natural & Organic",
                "icon": "",
                "state": {
                    "opened": false,
                    "disabled": false,
                    "selected": false
                },
                "children": false,
                "liAttributes": null,
                "aAttributes": null
            }, {
                "id": "2.08.0",
                "text": "Prepared Foods",
                "icon": "",
                "state": {
                    "opened": false,
                    "disabled": false,
                    "selected": false
                },
                "children": false,
                "liAttributes": null,
                "aAttributes": null
            }, {
                "id": "2.09.0",
                "text": "Seafood",
                "icon": "",
                "state": {
                    "opened": false,
                    "disabled": false,
                    "selected": false
                },
                "children": false,
                "liAttributes": null,
                "aAttributes": null
            }, {
                "id": "2.010.0",
                "text": "Seafood",
                "icon": "",
                "state": {
                    "opened": false,
                    "disabled": false,
                    "selected": false
                },
                "children": false,
                "liAttributes": null,
                "aAttributes": null
            }],
            "liAttributes": null,
            "aAttributes": null
        }, {
            "id": "2.0",
            "text": "Frozen Products",
            "icon": "",
            "state": {
                "opened": false,
                "disabled": false,
                "selected": false
            },
            "children": [],
            "liAttributes": null,
            "aAttributes": null
        }, {
            "id": "3.0",
            "text": "Store Equipment ",
            "icon": "",
            "state": {
                "opened": false,
                "disabled": false,
                "selected": false
            },
            "children": [],
            "liAttributes": null,
            "aAttributes": null
        }, {
            "id": "4.0",
            "text": "Packaged Grocery",
            "icon": "",
            "state": {
                "opened": false,
                "disabled": false,
                "selected": false
            },
            "children": [],
            "liAttributes": null,
            "aAttributes": null
        }, {
            "id": "5.0",
            "text": "Retail Technology",
            "icon": "",
            "state": {
                "opened": false,
                "disabled": false,
                "selected": false
            },
            "children": [],
            "liAttributes": null,
            "aAttributes": null
        }, {
            "id": "6.0",
            "text": "HBC/Non-Foods",
            "icon": "",
            "state": {
                "opened": false,
                "disabled": false,
                "selected": false
            },
            "children": [{
                "id": "2.090.0",
                "text": "Seafood",
                "icon": "",
                "state": {
                    "opened": false,
                    "disabled": false,
                    "selected": false
                },
                "children": false,
                "liAttributes": null,
                "aAttributes": null
            }],
            "liAttributes": null,
            "aAttributes": null
        }]



    },
    "search": {

        "case_insensitive": true,
        "show_only_matches" : true


    },

    "plugins": ["search"]


});
```

});